# how to Increase div height with scroll?

Tags: jquery, css, scrolltop

I am trying to design something like [this](https://www.netguru.com/about-us/company) timeline. I have already designed this but the problem is I'm unable to increase the div height as they did with scroll. I just need to increase the `.cm-timeline__path--active` div height with every pixel scrolled. I am really confused how can I achieve this.

I am using jQuery visible to check whether the parent div is in the viewport.

```js
! function(t) {
  var i = t(window);
  t.fn.visible = function(t, e, o) {
    if (!(this.length < 1)) {
      var r = this.length > 1 ? this.eq(0) : this,
        n = r.get(0),
        f = i.width(),
        h = i.height(),
        o = o ? o : "both",
        l = e === !0 ? n.offsetWidth * n.offsetHeight : !0;
      if ("function" == typeof n.getBoundingClientRect) {
        var g = n.getBoundingClientRect(),
          u = g.top >= 0 && g.top < h,
          s = g.bottom > 0 && g.bottom <= h,
          c = g.left >= 0 && g.left < f,
          a = g.right > 0 && g.right <= f,
          v = t ? u || s : u && s,
          b = t ? c || a : c && a;
        if ("both" === o) return l && v && b;
        if ("vertical" === o) return l && v;
        if ("horizontal" === o) return l && b
      } else {
        var d = i.scrollTop(),
          p = d + h,
          w = i.scrollLeft(),
          m = w + f,
          y = r.offset(),
          z = y.top,
          B = z + r.height(),
          C = y.left,
          R = C + r.width(),
          j = t === !0 ? B : z,
          q = t === !0 ? z : B,
          H = t === !0 ? R : C,
          L = t === !0 ? C : R;
        if ("both" === o) return !!l && p >= q && j >= d && m >= L && H >= w;
        if ("vertical" === o) return !!l && p >= q && j >= d;
        if ("horizontal" === o) return !!l && m >= L && H >= w
      }
    }
  }
}(jQuery);

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var div = $('.cm-timeline__path--active'),
    divHeight = div.height(),
    scroll;

  var st = $(this).scrollTop() / 6;
  if ($('.cm-timeline').visible(true)) {
    div.height(divHeight + st)
  } else {
    div.height(divHeight - st)
  }
});
```

```css
.cm-timeline {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 35px 0 44px;
  padding-bottom: 84px;
}

.cm-timeline:before,
.cm-timeline:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.cm-timeline:before {
  width: 417px;
  height: 173px;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/stars.png) 0 0/100% no-repeat;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.cm-timeline:after {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 158px;
  margin-left: -2px;
  height: 256px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__paths {
  position: relative;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__path {
  padding: 0 25px;
  display: block;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__path::before {
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 2.5px);
  bottom: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  content: "";
  background: #e5e5e5;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__start {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-bottom: 93px;
  padding: 25px;
  font-family: CamphorThin;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 800;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #00cdac;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 18px 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 345px;
  margin: 0 auto 55px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__start-inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__start-image {
  width: 94px;
  height: 52px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__start-title {
  width: auto;
  font-family: CamphorRegular;
  color: color(theme-dark);
  font-size: 18px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__company-logo {
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -30px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5000;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 18px 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 320px;
  margin: 35px auto;
  width: 374px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone:nth-child(2n) {
  left: 40px;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone:nth-child(odd) {
  right: 40px;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone:nth-child(odd):after {
  right: -6px;
  left: auto;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone:nth-child(odd) .cm-timeline__milestone-year {
  right: auto;
  left: 345px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone:nth-child(odd) .cm-timeline__milestone-year:not(.cm-timeline__milestone-year--empty) {
  padding: 0 22px 0 45px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone:nth-child(odd) .cm-timeline__milestone-year:not(.cm-timeline__milestone-year--empty):before {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone:nth-child(odd) .cm-timeline__milestone-year:after {
  left: 8px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone:nth-child(odd) .cm-timeline__milestone-year {
  left: 399px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone:after {
  top: 33px;
  left: -6px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  content: "";
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  display: block;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone-inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 56px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone-img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone-title {
  font-family: CamphorMedium;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: color(theme-dark);
  font-size: 16px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone-description {
  margin-top: 3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: color(theme-dark-gray);
  font-family: CamphorThin;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year {
  margin-top: 74px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone-year {
  top: -50px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 24px;
  font-family: Sailec;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
  color: #999;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: auto;
  height: 28px;
  top: auto;
  right: 345px;
  left: auto;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0 45px 0 22px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  transform: none;
  right: 399px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone-year:not(.cm-timeline__milestone-year--empty):before {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone-year:after {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone-year--empty {
  width: 28px;
  padding: 0;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__end {
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 122px auto 0;
  border: 5px solid #e5e5e5;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__path--active {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__path--active:before {
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 2.5px);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background: #00cdac;
  z-index: 0;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__path--active .cm-timeline__start {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__path--active .cm-timeline__milestone {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__path--active .cm-timeline__end {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #00cdac;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__path--active .cm-timeline__milestone-year {
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #00cdac;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__path--active .cm-timeline__milestone-year:after {
  background-color: #00cdac;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cm-timeline">
  <div class="cm-timeline__paths">
    <div class="cm-timeline__path">
      <div class="cm-timeline__start">
        <div class="cm-timeline__start-inner">
          <!-- <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/founders.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/founders@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__start-image" alt="founders"> -->
          <div class="cm-timeline__start-title">Project Started</div>
        </div>
        <!-- <img src="assets/images/fleapo-icon.svg" class="cm-timeline__company-logo" alt="company logo"> -->
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Process</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/sie-pomaga.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/sie-pomaga@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Launch of SiePomaga</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">the biggest charity website in the country</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Ideation</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/sie-pomaga.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/sie-pomaga@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Launch of SiePomaga</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">the biggest charity website in the country</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Collaboration</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/document.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/document@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Start of company's blog</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">https://netguru.com/blog</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Work</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/cup.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/cup@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Netguru wins the Aulery award</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">for the best tech companies with global potential</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Review</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/ios-android.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/ios-android@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Introducing iOS and Android development services</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Optimization</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/ledbury.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/ledbury@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Start of collaboration with Ledbury
            </div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">a US brick &amp; mortar retailer
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__end"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cm-timeline__path cm-timeline__path--active">
      <div class="cm-timeline__start">
        <div class="cm-timeline__start-inner">
          <!-- <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/founders.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/founders@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__start-image" alt="founders"> -->
          <div class="cm-timeline__start-title">Project Started</div>
        </div>
        <!-- <img src="assets/images/fleapo-icon.svg" class="cm-timeline__company-logo" alt="company logo"> -->
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Process</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/sie-pomaga.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/sie-pomaga@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Launch of SiePomaga</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">the biggest charity website in the country</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Ideation</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/sie-pomaga.png 1x, ttps://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/sie-pomaga@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
           </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Launch of SiePomaga</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">the biggest charity website in the country</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Collaboration</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/document.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/document@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Start of company's blog</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">https://netguru.com/blog</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Work</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/cup.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/cup@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Netguru wins the Aulery award</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">for the best tech companies with global potential</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Review</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/ios-android.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/ios-android@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
           </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Introducing iOS and Android development services</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Optimization</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/ledbury.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/ledbury@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Start of collaboration with Ledbury
            </div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">a US brick &amp; mortar retailer
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__end"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a tip, you should consider changing names of variables because right now they are perfectly unreadable. Also you reinitialize `o`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
! function(t) {
  var i = t(window);
  t.fn.visible = function(t, e, o) {
    if (!(this.length < 1)) {
      var r = this.length > 1 ? this.eq(0) : this,
        n = r.get(0),
        f = i.width(),
        h = i.height(),
        o = o ? o : "both",
        l = e === !0 ? n.offsetWidth * n.offsetHeight : !0;
      if ("function" == typeof n.getBoundingClientRect) {
        var g = n.getBoundingClientRect(),
          u = g.top >= 0 && g.top < h,
          s = g.bottom > 0 && g.bottom <= h,
          c = g.left >= 0 && g.left < f,
          a = g.right > 0 && g.right <= f,
          v = t ? u || s : u && s,
          b = t ? c || a : c && a;
        if ("both" === o) return l && v && b;
        if ("vertical" === o) return l && v;
        if ("horizontal" === o) return l && b
      } else {
        var d = i.scrollTop(),
          p = d + h,
          w = i.scrollLeft(),
          m = w + f,
          y = r.offset(),
          z = y.top,
          B = z + r.height(),
          C = y.left,
          R = C + r.width(),
          j = t === !0 ? B : z,
          q = t === !0 ? z : B,
          H = t === !0 ? R : C,
          L = t === !0 ? C : R;
        if ("both" === o) return !!l && p >= q && j >= d && m >= L && H >= w;
        if ("vertical" === o) return !!l && p >= q && j >= d;
        if ("horizontal" === o) return !!l && m >= L && H >= w
      }
    }
  }
}(jQuery);

  var div = $('.cm-timeline__path--active'),
    divHeight = div.height(),
    scroll;
$(window).scroll(function(event) {

  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (!$('.cm-timeline').visible(true)) {
    div.height(divHeight + st)
  } else {
    div.height(divHeight - st)
  }
});
```

```css
.cm-timeline {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 35px 0 44px;
  padding-bottom: 84px;
}

.cm-timeline:before,
.cm-timeline:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.cm-timeline:before {
  width: 417px;
  height: 173px;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/stars.png) 0 0/100% no-repeat;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.cm-timeline:after {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 158px;
  margin-left: -2px;
  height: 256px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__paths {
  position: relative;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__path {
  padding: 0 25px;
  display: block;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__path::before {
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 2.5px);
  bottom: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  content: "";
  background: #e5e5e5;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__start {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-bottom: 93px;
  padding: 25px;
  font-family: CamphorThin;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 800;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #00cdac;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 18px 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 345px;
  margin: 0 auto 55px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__start-inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__start-image {
  width: 94px;
  height: 52px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__start-title {
  width: auto;
  font-family: CamphorRegular;
  color: color(theme-dark);
  font-size: 18px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__company-logo {
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -30px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5000;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 18px 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 320px;
  margin: 35px auto;
  width: 374px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone:nth-child(2n) {
  left: 40px;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone:nth-child(odd) {
  right: 40px;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone:nth-child(odd):after {
  right: -6px;
  left: auto;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone:nth-child(odd) .cm-timeline__milestone-year {
  right: auto;
  left: 345px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone:nth-child(odd) .cm-timeline__milestone-year:not(.cm-timeline__milestone-year--empty) {
  padding: 0 22px 0 45px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone:nth-child(odd) .cm-timeline__milestone-year:not(.cm-timeline__milestone-year--empty):before {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone:nth-child(odd) .cm-timeline__milestone-year:after {
  left: 8px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone:nth-child(odd) .cm-timeline__milestone-year {
  left: 399px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone:after {
  top: 33px;
  left: -6px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  content: "";
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  display: block;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone-inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 56px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone-img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone-title {
  font-family: CamphorMedium;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: color(theme-dark);
  font-size: 16px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone-description {
  margin-top: 3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: color(theme-dark-gray);
  font-family: CamphorThin;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year {
  margin-top: 74px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone-year {
  top: -50px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 24px;
  font-family: Sailec;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
  color: #999;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: auto;
  height: 28px;
  top: auto;
  right: 345px;
  left: auto;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0 45px 0 22px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  transform: none;
  right: 399px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone-year:not(.cm-timeline__milestone-year--empty):before {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone-year:after {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__milestone-year--empty {
  width: 28px;
  padding: 0;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__end {
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 122px auto 0;
  border: 5px solid #e5e5e5;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__path--active {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__path--active:before {
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 2.5px);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background: #00cdac;
  z-index: 0;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__path--active .cm-timeline__start {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__path--active .cm-timeline__milestone {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__path--active .cm-timeline__end {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #00cdac;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__path--active .cm-timeline__milestone-year {
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #00cdac;
}

.cm-timeline .cm-timeline__path--active .cm-timeline__milestone-year:after {
  background-color: #00cdac;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cm-timeline">
  <div class="cm-timeline__paths">
    <div class="cm-timeline__path">
      <div class="cm-timeline__start">
        <div class="cm-timeline__start-inner">
          <!-- <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/founders.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/founders@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__start-image" alt="founders"> -->
          <div class="cm-timeline__start-title">Project Started</div>
        </div>
        <!-- <img src="assets/images/fleapo-icon.svg" class="cm-timeline__company-logo" alt="company logo"> -->
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Process</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/sie-pomaga.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/sie-pomaga@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Launch of SiePomaga</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">the biggest charity website in the country</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Ideation</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/sie-pomaga.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/sie-pomaga@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Launch of SiePomaga</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">the biggest charity website in the country</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Collaboration</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/document.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/document@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Start of company's blog</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">https://netguru.com/blog</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Work</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/cup.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/cup@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Netguru wins the Aulery award</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">for the best tech companies with global potential</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Review</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/ios-android.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/ios-android@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Introducing iOS and Android development services</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Optimization</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/ledbury.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/ledbury@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Start of collaboration with Ledbury
            </div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">a US brick &amp; mortar retailer
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__end"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cm-timeline__path cm-timeline__path--active">
      <div class="cm-timeline__start">
        <div class="cm-timeline__start-inner">
          <!-- <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/founders.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/founders@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__start-image" alt="founders"> -->
          <div class="cm-timeline__start-title">Project Started</div>
        </div>
        <!-- <img src="assets/images/fleapo-icon.svg" class="cm-timeline__company-logo" alt="company logo"> -->
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Process</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/sie-pomaga.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/sie-pomaga@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Launch of SiePomaga</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">the biggest charity website in the country</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Ideation</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/sie-pomaga.png 1x, ttps://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/sie-pomaga@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
           </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Launch of SiePomaga</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">the biggest charity website in the country</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Collaboration</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/document.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/document@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Start of company's blog</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">https://netguru.com/blog</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Work</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/cup.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/cup@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Netguru wins the Aulery award</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">for the best tech companies with global potential</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Review</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/ios-android.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/ios-android@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
           </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Introducing iOS and Android development services</div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__milestone cm-timeline__milestone--with-new-year">
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-year">Optimization</div>
        <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-inner">
          <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-img-wrap">
            <img srcset="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/ledbury.png 1x, https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/493098/images/company-timeline/ledbury@2x.png 2x" class="cm-timeline__milestone-img" alt="founders">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-title">Start of collaboration with Ledbury
            </div>
            <div class="cm-timeline__milestone-description">a US brick &amp; mortar retailer
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm-timeline__end"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have just removed the declaration of div and its height out of scroll function and your changed your condition. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Sir have you checked https://www.netguru.com/about-us/company
I need this kind of transition.

Comment: your .cm-timeline__path--active div is now getting height as per scroll which you want as per your description let me know what else you need extra on this

Comment: Can you take a  look here http://nayafleapo.herokuapp.com/about.html and identify the problem why its not working here?

Comment: For your site you need to do reduce the already scrolled from the current scroll top and that will be assigned to your div as height hope you got it.

Comment: Sir, if you dont mind can you just update the script?